# Changing content of a div on mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

CSS and Jquery.

I have created a table with three cells in each row. The content of the last cell of the row will be visible on mouse hover of the respective row. This portion I managed to do.

The HTML and CSS and Jquery I have written is as follows:

```
<html>
<style>
    tbody tr td div.show{
        display:none;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .show-child{
        display:none;
        cursor:pointer;
    }

    tbody tr:hover td div.show{
        display:block;
    }

</style>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>John</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td><div class="show">Edit</div> <div class="show-child">Save | Cancel</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Allan</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td><div class="show">Edit</div><div class="show-child">Save | Cancel</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Richi</td>
                <td>Doe</td>
                <td><div class="show">Edit</div><div class="show-child">Save | Cancel</div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.show').on('click',function(){//alert('aaaa');
            if($('.show').css('display')=='block'){//alert('aaaa');
                $('.show').css('display','none');
                $('.show-child').css('display','block');
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the last cell when I click on the "Edit" It will show Save and Cancel link. But when I click on the Edit all the rows are changing. I only want to change the Content of the respective cell.

And also I want to show a input type text in the 1st cell of the row in place of the name.

Please help me out.

Comment: This: `$('.show-child').css('display','block');` will show every child. It is doing exactly as you asked.

Comment: I only want to show the child on the respective row not on every row

Comment: Then you need to change it to be a contextual lookup.  `this` inside the click handler will be the show clicked.  You can find the show-child inside that with `$('.show-child', this)`. `$(selector)` is effectively the same thing as `$(selector, document)`, the second argument being the parent to find the elements in, which you can provide to override the default.

Comment: Can you just give me an example... Please

Answer (score 2):

When you use [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), inside of it, you have variable `this`.
In `this` variable you have element, you clicked on. So instead using CSS class selector, you can work with `this`.

```js
$('.show').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
    var td = $(this).parent('td');
    $(this).hide();
    $('.show-child', td).show();
  }
});
```

```css
tbody tr td div.show {
  display:none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.show-child {
  display:none;
  cursor:pointer;
}

tbody tr:hover td div.show {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td><div class="show">Edit</div> <div class="show-child">Save | Cancel</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Allan</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td><div class="show">Edit</div><div class="show-child">Save | Cancel</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Richi</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td><div class="show">Edit</div><div class="show-child">Save | Cancel</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
  $('.show').on('click',function(){//alert('aaaa');
 let parentElem=$(this).closest('tr')
$(parentElem).find('.s_f_name').css('display','none')    
$(parentElem).find('.s_l_name').css('display','none')    
$(parentElem).find('.t_f_name').css('display','block')
$(parentElem).find('.t_l_name').css('display','block')
    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
    $(this).hide();
    $(parentElem).find('.show-child').show()
    }     
});
```

```css
 tbody tr td div.show{
        display:none;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    .show-child{
        display:none;
        cursor:pointer;
    }

    tbody tr:hover td div.show{
        display:block;
    }
    
    .t_f_name{
    display:none
    }
    .t_l_name{
    display:none
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="s_f_name">John</span><input class='t_f_name' type=text ></td>
    <td><span class="s_l_name">Doe</span><input class='t_l_name' type=text ></td>
    <td><div class="show">Edit</div> <div class="show-child">Save | Cancel</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="s_f_name">Allan</span><input class='t_f_name' type=text ></td>
    <td><span class="s_l_name">Doe</span><input class='t_l_name' type=text ></td>
    <td><div class="show">Edit</div><div class="show-child">Save | Cancel</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="s_f_name">Richi</span><input class='t_f_name' type=text ></td>
    <td><span class="s_l_name">Doe</span><input class='t_l_name' type=text ></td>
    <td><div class="show">Edit</div><div class="show-child">Save | Cancel</div></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
```